# Error code in C++ assignment

Tags: c++

I have an assignment for school in C++, and I keep getting the 
" [Linker error] undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
ld returned 1 exit status "
errors. What does this mean, and how can I fix my program? Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

void wonderland()
{
     string answer;
     string nameanswer;
     string whoanswer;
     cout<<"Are you lost?"<<endl;
     cin>> answer;
     if (answer=="yes")
     {
     cout<<"Why, you are in wonderland, my dear!"<<endl;
     cout<<"Are you Alice?"<<endl;
     cin>> nameanswer;
     cout<<"Are you who you say you are..?"<<endl;
     cin>> whoanswer;
     system("pause");
     }
}
```

By the way, my teacher has his students use Dev C++, if it means any difference with the error code.

Comment: Every program needs a main function (or WinMain in special cases on Windows)... Do you have one?

Comment: Was your problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

Your program needs a `main`function and also you need to link your application with `subsystem:console`

Answer (score 0):

Every program must have main function: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/program_structure

This is cross-platform variant.

This error `WinMain@16' seems that your project's type is Windows Application. It is usefull for GUI application with windows forms
You must choose Console application type and place your code inside function "main"

Answer (score 0):

1 - If that`s your whole program then try the following code:

```
int main()
{
    string answer;
    string nameanswer;
    string whoanswer;
    cout<<"Are you lost?"<<endl;
    cin>> answer;
    if (answer=="yes")
    {
         cout<<"Why, you are in wonderland, my dear!"<<endl;
         cout<<"Are you Alice?"<<endl;
         cin>> nameanswer;
         cout<<"Are you who you say you are..?"<<endl;
         cin>> whoanswer;
         system("pause");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

2 - If you already had main function then refer to the link:      http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/42284/

3 - You may also try restarting the IDE.

4 - Instead of using a project template, you may create an empty project and add the cpp and header files explicitly as needed, which will resolve the linking issues.